# The Project Roadmap for Material

Tags: cosmicmind

The work looks great, and I'm thinking about new visual components that would be useful such as rivers.

Is there a roadmap for this project, and if not, could we create one?

Comment: for example, cards are great, but are river components being thought about, designed, considered?

Answer (score 0):

We are working on a roadmap during the month of March, with the addition of new features that we have planned to release. There will be quite a few new features coming to Material, as well, refinements of current ones. The roadmap will be shared shortly. If you have any feature requests, make a GitHub issue suggesting them.

All the best :)